# Windows XP "Base System Device"

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers, acer-aspire-one

I've got an old Acer Aspire One 531h laptop my friend gave me. I'm trying to make some use out of it, so I did a fresh install of Windows XP. All my devices and hardware (as far as I know) work. Yet when I go into Device Manager, under `Other Devices` I get something called a "Base System Device". What is this, and where can I get the drivers for it. Windows does not automatically install the drivers, and bugs me when I start it up to install the drivers.

 The device instance ID is `PCI\VEN_197B&DEV_2382&SUBSYS_022C1025&REV_00\4&2F707902&0&00E3`

Comment: Windows 10 is way out of support snd not even much good for web browsing. Why not use a lightweight Linux distro instead?

Comment: I would like to use this laptop for retro gaming

Comment: Retro gaming is fine, just don't put it online, ever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the vendor ID (197B) and the device ID (2382) it would appear that this device is a JMicron JMB38x SD/MMC PCIe card reader. You can find this information easily for most devices by just putting their hardware ID (*not* the device instance ID, that's too unique) in your favorite internet search engine.

Windows XP drivers are not available for this device, you cannot use it. Not a problem for your retro gaming plans though!